# How spicy are my peppers?

Tags: probability, statistics

This came naturally to me when I studied statistics ~10 years ago, but for the life of me I can't remember how to work this out:

---

For a given chilli pepper, there is (let's say exactly) $1/100$ chance that the flavour is exceptionally spicy.

In a bag of 30 peppers, if I eat all of them, what is the chance that I encounter an exceptionally spicy chilli?

---

I wanted to say that the chance was $30/100 = 0.3$, but quickly realised I was wrong as I know I'm not guaranteed to have eaten a spicy pepper if I eat 100.

How can I work this out please?

Comment: Yes, $30/100$ is the expected number of such peppers in the bag. It is easier to compute the probability that you *don't* get an exceptionally got pepper.

Comment: +1. wanted to +1 more than once for "I wanted to say that the chance was 30/100=0.3, but quickly realised I was wrong as I know I'm not guaranteed to have eaten a spicy pepper if I eat 100." It's such an important skill to be able to critically analyze your assumptions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of *not* eating a spicy pepper is $(1-1/100)$ which means that if we eat 30 then the chance of getting away without eating a spicy one is $(99/100)^{30}$ and thus our probability of eating *at least* one spicy pepper is $1-(99/100)^{30} \approx0.26$

Comment: +1 but the question is for 30, be sure to modify your answer.

Comment: @hunter, Thankfully this was enough to kickstart the part of my brain that understood this once upon a time and I could apply it to my numbers.